# im trying to add randNumber to to playerOneNum in js by using rollBtn

Tags: javascript

i want it so i can add randNumber to the existing number in playerOneNum. this is my code until now

```
const rollBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('btn--new')[0];

let playerOneNum = document.getElementById('current--0');

console.log(playerOneNum.textContent)

rollBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let randNumber = Math.floor(math.random() * 7)
    let outcome = playerOneNum.textContent + randNumber.textContent;

});
```

Comment: `playerOneNum.textContent=outcome;`? Oh. `randNumber` is a number, it has no `.textContent`, but you can append it directly to text: `let outcome = playerOneNum.textContent + randNumber;`. All this assumes that `playerOneNum` is something with `textContent`.

Comment: @tevemadar they are both to number that i want to add, thats all

Comment: Then you will have to show more of the code. It might be `let outcome=parseInt(playerOneNum.textContent)+randNumber;` what you need, but it may be something else.

Comment: @tevemadar thats the only code i have, ur code doesn't work :(